# PHP: any function that i give as arguments the array and a key of that array and it returns the value of the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$a = array('it' => 'italiano',
                 'fr' => 'francese',
                 'en' => 'inglese',
                 'es' => 'spagnolo',
                 'de' => 'deutsch',

               );
```

Is there any function that i give as arguments the array and a key (for example 'en') and it returns 'inglese'?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't necessitate a function.  This is just standard array access logic.

```
$a['en']
```

Or if `$key` was 'en', then

```
$a[$key]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$languageName = 'Default';
$languageCode = 'en';
if (isset($a[$languageCode])) {
   $languageName = $a[$languageCode];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using `$a['en']`? Which would give 'inglese' as well.

```
function get_value($array, $key){
  return (isset($array[$key]) ? $array[$key] : null;
}

echo get_value($array, 'en'); # => echoes inglese
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function language($array, $language){
    if(isset($array[$language]))
       return $array[$language];
    else 
       return false;
}

$language = language($a, 'en');

if($language != false)
  echo $language;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this

```
$a = array(
      'it' => 'italiano',
      'fr' => 'francese',
      'en' => 'inglese',
      'es' => 'spagnolo',
      'de' => 'deutsch',
     );

$lang = 'it';
echo getValueFromKey($a,$lang);

function getValueFromKey($array,$key) {
   return $array[$key];
}
```

or like this

```
echo $a['it'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply do:

```
echo $a['en'];
```

This will give you `inglese`

Comment: I don't know why but I can't undo my -1 vote :( I must have done something wrong... sorry.